# Open Browser Popup in Liferay via Vaadin

Tags: liferay, vaadin, liferay-6, popupwindow, vaadin7

using Vaadin 7.1 and Liferay 6.1 I try to open a new UI (in the same session) in a new browser window using com.vaadin.server.BrowserWindowOpener:

```
Button button = new Button("button");
BrowserWindowOpener windowOpener = new BrowserWindowOpener(OverviewWindow.class);
windowOpener.extend(button);
```

Where `OverviewWindow extends UI` is a trivial custom UI.

In standalone use (i.e. *without* Liferay) this works fine, but in Liferay the popup opens and displays "Request was not handled by any registered handler." (HTTP-Response-Code: 404).

I tried many things - among others to generate the url via `com.liferay.portlet.PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(PortletRequest, String, long, String)` - but nothing works.

Has anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried this `getUI().getPage().open(url,"_blank",true);` ?

Comment: No I didnt try this - but this would open only some _URL_ and not a new _UI_ - correct?

Comment: Yes indeed. I don't understand why you want to open a new UI you should use `View` with the `Navigator` to navigate between pages. If you want to open an `UI` you have to use `UiProvider` or go [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/2466847) and you'll see that you have to add "_blank" property to the opener. Hope that help!

Comment: Hm - I indeed want to create a new `UI`. Of course one could manually fiddle around with `UIProvider`s, but the question was if one can get the default way (i.e. using `BrowserWindowOpener`) to work within a portal/liferay. Thanks anyways @TantaouiElMehdi!

Comment: It appears to be a bug - created a ticket: http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/13957