# How to render a Vaadin view from backend

Tags: servlets, vaadin, restful-url

In my application, the remote client is making a restful call to a backend method, say

`@POST Response lookup(@Context HttpServletRequest request)`.

Then, if the request parameters satisfy certain conditions, 
an Vaadin view, say `ResultView` is supposed to be rendered to client's browser. in other cases, `lookup()` returns without any confrontation with `MyUI`.

This boils down to creating a UI instance from the backend(?) How to do this? I tried (1) below and found out about (2).

1.) put  `@POST Response lookup(@Context HttpServletRequest request)` into `myUI`. For this, i added to `MyUI` `@Path("/lookup")`. This is the only change I made to MyUI. 
The following are the annotations on `MyUI` now:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("mytheme")
@Path("/lookup")
```

I havent changed `web.xml` mapping for the restful calls:

[image]

This didn't show any errors. However, didn't invoke `lookup()`.

2.) make UIProvider create a UI instance as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919487/open-browser-popup-in-liferay-via-vaadin) post.

Vaadin @Push wouldn't work for this, i have to invoke a UI explicitly.

This may be a naive question, however i'm a backend developer-- not well familiar with servlet containers and this is my first time with Vaadin.

TIA

Comment: I am not completly sure if I understand what you are up to or what's the reason for such a handling.  In general vaadin is not used as a "render me some html" - but for SPA. So my best guess here would be to do a redirect in your lookup (e.g. "post on lookup with firstName=roam", do the lookup's work and redirect to /myUi#!/users/42) - BTW: please don't use images for code.  just paste the code in your question.

Comment: Vaadin serverside is not meant to be used that way. It generates the whole page via javascript, so your REST access won't work, it does not return html